# __forceinline and inline usage

Tags: c++, visual-c++, inlining

When using __forceinline or inline inside of a class do I have to include the definition inside of the header file in MSVC? I've heard mixed opinions on this that vary through different compilers.

Example 1:

```
//some_class.hpp
class some_class
{
public:
   __forceinline void some_function();
   inline void other_function();
};

//some_class.cpp
void some_class::some_function() { }
void some_class::other_function() { }
```

Example 2:

```
//some_class.hpp
class some_class
{
public:
   __forceinline void some_function() { }
   inline void other_function() { }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MSVC leaving function definition in .cpp file causes `unresolved external symbol` error when linking if function was previously explicitly declared as `inline`, `__inline` or `__forceinline`. So I guess one must put function definition into header. Which makes sense because in order to actually inline the function it's body must be available for compiler.